# How can I convert this code to VB.NET from C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
var invoices = New List <InvoiceDto> {New() {
    body = New() {body},
    header = header,
    Payments = New() {payment}
    }
    };
```

I try this code but I get error

> Unable to cast object of type 'TaxCollectData.Library.Dto.Content.InvoiceBodyDto' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TaxCollectData.Library.Dto.Content.InvoiceBodyDto]'.

```
Dim invoices As New List(Of InvoiceDto)(New InvoiceDto() With {
        .Header = header,
        .Body = New List(Of InvoiceBodyDto)(body),
        .Payments = New List(Of PaymentDto)(payment)
        }
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were passing single items in your `List(Of ...)` constructors. You [need to pass an enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))), which you create by enclosing an item in curly braces.

```vb
Dim invoices As New List(Of InvoiceDto)(
    {New InvoiceDto() With {
        .Header = header,
        .Body = New List(Of InvoiceBodyDto)({body}),
        .Payments = New List(Of PaymentDto)({payment})
        }
    })
```

Comment: The other answer that uses collection initializers is probably better (more efficient), because it creates an empty list and then it adds the items. In my answer, on the other hand, the line  `New List(Of InvoiceBodyDto)({body})` first creates an array with one item `body`, this array is passed to the constructor and the constructor adds the item from the array. The array creation is unnecessary overhead, unless the compiler is clever enough and optimizes the code, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Your [collection Initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) is wrong, it should be:

```
Dim invoices As New List(Of InvoiceDto) From {
    New InvoiceDto() With {
        .Header = header,
        .Body = New List(Of InvoiceBodyDto) From {body},
        .Payments = New List(Of PaymentDto) From {payment}
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this error "Unable to cast object of type 'TaxCollectData.Library.Dto.Content.InvoiceDto' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TaxCollectData.Library.Dto.Content.InvoiceDto]"

Comment: Same problem, I've fixed it.

Comment: This should have been marked as the answer (the other answer is missing 'From').

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Yes, the other answer is missing From because it uses another approach - IEnumerable passed to the List constructor. And it works. Have you tried it?